# If all directional derivatives are $0$, the function is constant.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable in every point of the disc $
B_{r}(\vec{a})$. If $D_{\vec{y}}f(\vec{x})=0$ for $n$ linearly independent vectors $\vec{y}_{1}, \vec{y}_{2},...,\vec{y}_{n}$ and $\forall \vec{x} \in B_{r}(\vec{a})$, show that $f$ is constant.

**I've proven the following statement:**

Let $f$ be a function of $n$ variables such that the directional derivatives $D_{\vec{y}}f(\vec{a}+t\vec{y})$ exist $\forall t \in [0,1]$. Then, there exists a real number $\theta \in ]0,1[$ such that:

\begin{equation}
f(\vec{a}+\vec{y})-f(\vec{a}) =  D_{\vec{y}}f(\vec{a}+\theta \vec{y}) 
\end{equation}

I believe that this question may be answered by means of a corollary of this last statement, or by using a similar version of the **Mean Value Theorem**. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the directional derivative is zero for $n$ linearly independent vectors, then it is zero in *every* direction, since the linearly independent vectors span the entire vector space. More explicitly, $D_{\vec{y}} f(\vec{x}) = \langle \nabla f(\vec{x}),\vec{y} \rangle$, and if $\nabla f(\vec{x})$ is orthogonal to $n$ linearly independent vectors then it is orthogonal to $\mathbb{R}^n$ and must be zero. Your mean value theorem now shows that the function is constant.

Comment: Thank you Yuval, I have only one question. If a vector is orthogonal to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ it must be zero? How can we know this?

Comment: If a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$ then in particular it is orthogonal to itself, and so has zero norm.